# Qt C++ XML, validating against a DTD?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dtd, qtxml

Is there a way to validate an XML file against a DTD with Qt's XML handling? I've tried googling around but can't seem to get a straight answer. If Qt doesn't include support for validating an XML file, what might be the process of implementing validation myself? Any good reference to start with in regards to validating XML against a spec? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocumenttype.html#QDomDocumentType, Qt's DTD representation class!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate your XML with this : http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qxmlschema.html

You can also find an example here : [XML Schema Validation Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/xmlpatterns-schema.html)

Hope it helps a bit !

Comment: So I won't be able to validate with a DTD but with an XML schema? I haven't heard of "XML Schema" before but it looks to do what I need it to do, thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of something related to DTD with Qt... I think you'll have to go with that... But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Qt Linguist uses DTD for it's TS translation XML files.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/linguist-ts-file-format.html

Comment: You are wrong, you can use DTD's, you should check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocumenttype.html#QDomDocumentType, Qt's DTD representation class!